# Should I even care for level 4 warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I'm making a medium-sized project (a game engine) and I once decided that it would be good to to enable all warnings (`/Wall`). Then I saw the massive amount of totally useless warnings like:

```
Warning C4820   '<unnamed-tag>': '3' bytes padding added after data member <unnamed-tag>::Data' DirectX11 Engine    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h  14179
```

Then I decided to use `/W4`. There's still plenty of useless warnings even though some of them could actually help me out tracking bugs. Some examples:

```
Warning C4359   'btContactConstraint': Alignment specifier is less than actual alignment (128), and will be ignored.    BulletDynamics  c:\bullet3-2.83.5\src\bulletdynamics\constraintsolver\btContactConstraint.h 25
Warning C4100   'FirstObject': unreferenced formal parameter    DirectX11 Engine    b:\game engine\directx11 engine\directx11 engine\character.cpp  240
```

**Why should someone care for level 4 wanings?** I think that level 4 warnings should be ignored because I would spend more time checking them than I would spend tracking down a bug. So `/W3` is perfect for me.

EDIT: Of course, in the end of the project I would use `/W4` and take a look at which warnings could mean something useful.

Comment: I once saw someone maintaining a list of warnings you should ignore in MSVC, but I imagine this requires constant maintenance to keep up with the new versions...

Comment: You brought in the close reason for your question within itself: _"marily opinion-based
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Changed it. Is it better like this?

Comment: Nope, not really. Still opinion based.

Comment: This statement "level 4 warnings should be ignored because I would spend more time checking them than I would spend tracking down a bug", most likely, is false. Also, in the end of the project you'd have an overwhelming amount of warnings to go through.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not completely anymore, though.

Comment: @LHLaurini Well, which **facts** did you receive besides opinions actually? There's a nice XKCD comic as wel, coming up with a raptor biting you in your back (front, ass). Don't ignore warnings, fix them instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: As far as I understand, MSVC has a lot of nonsense warnings that are genuinely unactionable. It seems sensible that you'd want a way to enable as many warnings as possible and then exclude the silly ones.

Comment: Use `/W4`, not `/Wall`. Some warnings are disabled by default and are only enabled if `/Wall` is specified (if you specify `/W4`, it will not enable these off-by-default warnings). Most of the "useless" warnings are disabled by default.  C4820 is off by default. C4359 is useful as it warns you that you've specified something in the source that the compiler is _ignoring_. C4100 is useful as it warns you that you've named something in the source that you aren't using (potentially by accident).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unfortunately VS has a lot of really useless warnings.  I still recommend though that you use the maximum level and then disable specific warnings you're not interested in.  You gleam good information from warnings.  For example, the alignment issues your compiler is complaining about could slow down the execution of your program.  Up to you and your requirements as to whether that matters.

Comment: Thanks. Most warnings are C4244 (possible loss of data). It's not like I don't know that 'double' to 'float' can cause loss of data. That's an example of warning I should disable, then? Also there are many warnings in Windows, DirectX and Bullet headers, so should I disable all warnings for these headers and then enable them again?

Comment: @LHLaurini C4244 should be considered a critical warning and should absolutely not be disabled. Unexpected narrowing is a common cause of security bugs. For a recent example of such a critical defect, see http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2015/09/stagefrightened.html (this is something for which C4244 would be issued were the code compiled with Visual C++).

Answer (score 1):

In general yes, you should compile with as a high a level of warning as possible. Even though **some may seem useless, some won't be. It is that very investigation that is the desirable aspect of the warning** that you are looking for.

Sure, you also need to be pragmatic about this, if the code all still works in spite of the warnings, ignore them for the time being. I would take a considered approach if the volume is too much; work through the warnings over time.

In general, **the warnings very instructive and they lead to improvements in the code.** I also selectively turn off the warning when I know that the constraints that are required to ignore it are being met (e.g. dll exports).